# ListView dividers don't appear with cells background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, divider

I have a custom ListView and I want to display thin gradient dividers between my cells. Here is the XML of my ListView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/fil"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:clickable="true">
</ListView>
```

In my list_divider.xml, I have a gradient defined like this :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:centerColor="#999999"
            android:endColor="#00000000"
            android:startColor="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Normally, this would display a gradient divider, but it doesn't work. Apparently, the problem  is located in my row layout with a RelativeLayout root :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="5dip" >
```

When I put no background, it's working. But when I want to add a white background for example, it displays a full black divider. What's the problem here ?

Thanks